# what is the FFT logic in calculating far field defraction matlab implemetation

Tags: matlab, fft

There is an expression shown bellow that we need to plot in 2D grid plot as shown bellow.
X and Y are 2D matrices going from -0.5 to 0.5.
The Code uses an `FFT` function. `FFT` takes as input the `func_in` struct variable which has two subvariables:

1. The matrices which is the formula output data
2. Scale variable and some n variable.

Then `FFT` function does some `FFT2` which is described as
`Y = fft2(X)` returns the two-dimensional Fourier transform of a matrix using a fast Fourier transform algorithm.

Then they do
`Y = fftshift(X)` rearranges a Fourier transform X by shifting the zero-frequency component to the center of the array.

Then they use the `s`c with `linspace` of interval long vector.

What is the logic in the FFT Matlab code?

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc} I = |u_{out}|^2 = 40XY\sinc^2(10x)\sinc^2(y)\cos^2\left(\frac{3\pi y}{2}\right)$$

[image]

FFT function:

```
function [ func_out ] = FFT( func_in,n )
func_out.mat=fftshift(fft2(func_in.mat));
interval=(func_in.sc(2)-func_in.sc(1))^-1;
func_out.sc=linspace(-interval/2,interval/2,n);% FFT creates a new scale for the output. the scale is the ratio of one over the interval of the formaer scale.  
end
```

Main function:

```
L=1;
n=1024;
scale = linspace(-L/2,L/2,n);
[X , Y]= meshgrid(scale, scale);
rect=400*((sinc(10*X)).^2).*((sinc(Y)).^2).*cos(pi*3*Y./2);
func_in.mat=rect;
func_in.sc=scale;
func_out=FFT(func_in,n);
figure (1)
colormap gray

image(scale, scale, rect, 'CDataMapping','scaled');
```